# android picasso library add token header

Tags: android, token, picasso

I have been breaking my brain on this one,

I am using Picasso library to load and download images from my server, but now I want to add a header in my download request and I cant seem to find a way of doing it. all i want to do is set a header like : 
setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

I use this header in any of my server requests, but cant find a way to add it to the picasso line.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Picasso` uses `OkHttp` as *engine* , or it is possible to configure Picasso to use it, and since you have to set the header of the http request, you can use an `Interceptor`. E.g. this is my Interceptor to handle basic authentication:

```
private static class BasicAuthInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        final Request original = chain.request();
        final Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .header("Authorization", "Basic " + BASIC_AUTH_ENCODED)
        .method(original.method(), original.body());
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

and the you add the Interceptor to OkHttp like

```
 OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
 okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new BasicAuthInterceptor());
```

Last step is to configure `Picasso` to use `okHttpClient`. 
The Picasso's builder provide a method for it :

```
new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient)).build();
```

gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.0.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

Comment: you should follow this approach.

Comment: thanks alot! what is the compile line for okhttpclient?

Comment: also I see that Interceptor isnt provided in my android studio, does it come with the OkHttpclient? because at the moment I cant implement it

Comment: You are probably missing the depency in your gradle

Comment: the dependency is the same one for interceptor and the httpclient?

Comment: Yes, everything is part of OkHttp

Comment: where do i input the url?

Comment: A special downloader is needed as well: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-2-5-integrate-okhttp3-as-network-stack