# Picasso load image with HTTP post

Tags: android, json, http-post, picasso, image-loading

My API having some verification mechanism for every HTTP request. One of the end-point have the functionality to load a image using HTTP post method. The post request body will contain a JSON object which is verified from the server side.

For that i need to include a JSON like this on the http post request body.

```
{
    "session_id": "someId",
    "image_id": "some_id"
}
```

how can I do this with Picasso ?

Comment: do you want to download image with header?

Comment: no, i want to know how to send a post request using Picasso.

Comment: you can customize your request using custom downloader in picasso. Picasso uses okhttpclient as downloader.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455084/android-picasso-library-add-token-header

Comment: Thanks  Mr.Jackson Chengalai. It works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got the solution from the hint given by Mr.Jackson Chengalai.

Create a Okhttp request interceptor

```
private static class PicassoInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {

        final MediaType JSON
                = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("session_id", session_id);
        map.put("image", image);
        String requestJsonBody = new Gson().toJson(map);
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, requestStringBody);
        final Request original = chain.request();
        final Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
                .url(url)
                .post(body);
        return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Create a Okhttp client add this interceptor

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new PicassoInterceptor());
```

Create a Dowloader using this okhttp client

```
OkHttpDownloader = downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient)
```

Build Picasso using this downloader

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(downloader ).build();
```

Comment: which version/versions of Picasso does this work on?

Comment: picasso:2.5.2 and okhttp:2.7.2

Comment: We can add the url of the image in the Picasso.load(url). How to add the post body parameters?

Comment: @amasiddawadeyar please refer code inside the "intercept" method of my answer.