# Lazy load of images from server (post request) using Picasso

Tags: android, image, lazy-loading, picasso

I have a ListView, each of its rows has some text data...and an image. The request that brings the text data does not include the image, since it would be very long to receive all the image at the same time. I am searching about lazy loading of the images using Picasso, but all the examples I have read use a GET request, with an url. The service I am asking the images has a method to return me the image, but its a POST request.

Is there any way to use Picasso using a POST request, in order to lazy load the images for my ListView?

Thanks.

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35155189/833647

Comment: Yeah, its duplicated. Didn't found it before asking...Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Use this code in Adpter where you setting the listView items. 
`Picasso.with(context).load(list.get(position).getImage()).into(imageView);`