# Set image downloaded (with interceptor) using Picasso

Tags: android, lazy-loading, picasso

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151309/picasso-load-image-with-http-post) answer, I am trying to lazy loading images in a ListView using Picasso. This is my code:

```
public class PicassoInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private String param1;
private String param2;
private String param3;
private int param4;
private String param5;

public PicassoInterceptor(String param1, String param2, String param3, int param4, String param5) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
    this.param3 = param3;
    this.param4 = param4;
    this.param5 = param5;
}

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    final MediaType JSON
            = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("param1", param1);
    map.put("param2", param2);
    map.put("param3", param3);
    map.put("param4", String.valueOf(param4));
    String requestJsonBody = new Gson().toJson(map);
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(JSON, requestJsonBody);
    final Request original = chain.request();
    final Request.Builder requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
            .url(param5)
            .post(body);
    return chain.proceed(requestBuilder.build());
}
}
```

The adapter, inside getView method:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient.interceptors().add(new PicassoInterceptor(param1, param2,param3,param4, param5));

    OkHttpDownloader downloader = new OkHttpDownloader(okHttpClient);
    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).downloader(downloader).build();
```

Now, if I have understood it correctly, the images are downloaded. But, how to set it in the image view?

EDIT:

The image is received in BASE64.

Comment: Not the way I intended, had to ask the server guy to change the method from POST to GET, and build the URL. That way, is working, but didn't managed to make it work with POST.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
picasso.load(param5).fit().into(imageView);
```

It doesn't really matter which url you give the load() function - because you overwrite it in the interceptor. But I'd still give a legit one - to avoid problems.

Or you can edit your interceptor this way: [Picasso load image with HTTP post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151309/picasso-load-image-with-http-post)

Comment: And photoUri is...? I have got no URI.

Comment: Picasso is for loading images, so you must have an image you want to load. The "load" function can get File, Uri, URL or resource ID.

What image do you want to load?

Comment: I know  what Picasso is for. The problem is, I need to download images using a POST request, that is why I used an Interceptor, since the "default" usage is using GET request. Since the URL will be always the same (because its a post request) your way would not work.

Comment: Ahh you didn't write that the URL doesn't change. So it's always the same URL and you get different images by changing the body of the request?

Comment: Its a post request, URL is the same, and params are in the body. That is the params in the constructor are for. The server gets those parameters, and returns the proper image.

Comment: I've edited the answer with the new info you gave me

Comment: Yes. The execution is running over it, and I put a Log to see which item I am asking for, and the Log is shown.

Comment: If you see my interceptor is almost exactly the same way...its the answer I linked in my question.

Comment: I am almost out of the office. I will keep on searching monday. Thanks for your help, A-S, anyway. And good luck in Hattrick ;)

Comment: You edit the url in the interceptor.... But by sending the same url to the load() function - you should get the same results - or in other words: my answer should work for you.

Comment: He calls it url, I call it param5.

Comment: I am sending the same url in the Interceptor and the load function. NVM, will be easier to change the function in the server from POST to GET.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `into()` method and pass ImageView:

```
Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).into(imageView).downloader(downloader).build();
```

Comment: That does not work. Can't call into method where you wrote it.

Comment: You need to create aconstructor and just pass a imageView in this class PicassoInterceptor

Comment: But i can't call into method where you put it...also, this code is in the adapter of the ListView, not the interceptor.