# How to add Basic Authentication in Picasso 2.5.2 with OkHttp 3.2.0

Tags: android, okhttp, picasso

I am using picasso 2.5.2 library to download bitmap from remote server, the image url requires basic authentication in header.

i have tried the following SO ansers but none of them work with the latest picasso and OkHttp libraries.

[Answer - 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273783/android-picasso-library-how-to-add-authentication-headers)

[Answer - 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126223/how-to-add-authentication-token-in-header-in-picasso-library)

[Answer - 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455084/android-picasso-library-add-token-header)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your code - how do you want to authenticate? Have you looked into the [Retrofit docs](https://futurestud.io/blog/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit). `Retrofit2.Builder()` has a property called `authorization`, which is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: I am not looking for adding basic authentication with retrofit rest api calls, i need to add basic authentication with picasso for downloading images.

Comment: If you looked like 5 seconds in the provided link, you would have found a way to configure a `okhttp3` client modification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try configuring an OkHttp3 client with authenticator, depending on your scheme and situation:

```
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .authenticator(new Authenticator()
                {
                    @Override
                    public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException
                    {
                        String credential = Credentials.basic("user", "pass");
                        return response.request().newBuilder()
                                .header("Authorization", credential)
                                .build();
                    }
                })
            .build();
```

Then, use that client in forming your Picasso object, but with okhttp3 you will have to use a OkHttp3Downloader instead, like so:

```
    Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context)
        .downloader(new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient))
        .build();
```

You can get the OkHttp3Downloader from https://github.com/JakeWharton/picasso2-okhttp3-downloader

Comment: Okey, i will try this and inform u asap,any way thanks for your quick response and code snippet.

Comment: Perfect...works like charm...OkHttp3Downloader dependency is the key to success..

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me finally how you are setting the image to a ImageView.

Comment: nvm, my server was acting up!

Comment: It's no longer necessary to use Jake Wharton's library. This functionality comes with Picasso itself (version 2.71828, at least).