# Load password protected image to imageview with Picasso Image loader Library in android

Tags: android

i am getting an image url which is protected with password.I know how to do it with the Authenticator but i want to do this with Picasso.
Can anyone please tell me that how to load password protected images to a imageview with Picasso Image loader Library.

Below is the code to do with Authenticator:

```
private Bitmap download_Image(String url) {

            Bitmap bmp = null;
            try {
                URL ulrn = new URL(url);
                Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(imagePassword, "mypass".toCharArray());
                    }
                });
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) ulrn.openConnection();
                InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                if (null != bmp)
                    return bmp;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bmp;

        }
```

Comment: How do you do it with authenticator? could you show us please? how do you pass the password to the url?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for. The post says it could be done using Okhttp.

[How to add Basic Authentication in Picasso 2.5.2 with OkHttp 3.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36786158/how-to-add-basic-authentication-in-picasso-2-5-2-with-okhttp-3-2-0)

Good luck. :)

**Edit**

You can set the image to your image view like below.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("YOUR IMAGE URL HERE").into(imageView);
```

Comment: Thankx for your answer, but can you please tell me finally how to set the image to a image view?

Comment: @Akshaykumar Do you have the url of the image? Check my updated answer.

Comment: By this way we can do normally but my the url is protected with password, so how to do that this the problem.

Comment: The link in my answer has details. You can follow that. You have to authenticate using Okhttp.